# Floating Labels on Bootstrap 5 isn't working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

My floating labels aren't working, can someone help me?

[image]

**Code**

```html
<div class="form-floating mb-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" autofocus id="txtNome" placeholder=" ">
    <label for="txtNome">Full Name</label>
</div>
<div class="form-floating mb-3">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" autofocus id="txtEmail" 
        placeholder=" ">
    <label for="txtEmail">E-mail</label>
</div>
<div class="form-floating mb-3">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="txtMensagem" placeholder=" " 
              style="height: 200px;"></textarea>
    <label for="txtMensagem">Message</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Mine doesn't look like yours, but it's definitely not working.  The transitions (animations) are not happening and the styles looks weird.  I am using bootstrap 5.0.2 and tried both importing as normal and using their CDN and neither work.  The only upvoted answer doesn't work either.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Add this

Answer (score 4):

I think there may be an issue with adding Bootstrap CDN link. When I add it, I could take the view like the image you attached.

```html
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
 <body>
 <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" autofocus id="txtNome" placeholder=" ">
                        <label for="txtNome">Full Name</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" autofocus id="txtEmail" placeholder=" ">
                        <label for="txtEmail">E-mail</label>
                    </div>                  
                    
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="txtMensagem" placeholder=" " style="height: 200px;" ></textarea>
                        <label for="txtMensagem">Message</label>
                    </div>
</body>
```

You can take the Bootstrap CDN link using this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer helped you, you can mark this as the correct answer or can upvote this. It can be useful for another one.

Comment: This ended up correcting the issue for me. Something weird is up with Bootstrap's CDN link.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you added the correct CSS, Javascript and Jquery files for Bootstrap 5. These are the files you need to import into your code.

CSS

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Javascript

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Jquery

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Bootstrap 5 does not use or require jQuery.